# sushiswap flash loan never makes a profitable trade?

Tags: hardhat, fantom, sushiswap

Any ideas as to why this flashloan contract isn't working?

- getting prices from a pricing aggregator
- I've verified the prices are accurate
- Thought that maybe it was because of slippage/liquidity but liquidity seems fine but even small amounts aren't profitable
- I first use the price aggregator to find arbitrage positions. Ex: FTM/USDC is cheaper on tombswap than on spookyswap
- the contract then does a flash loan on sushiswap for FTM, swaps for USDC on one DEX, swaps back for FTM on the other, then tries to repay the loan
- The contract always reverts on the assertion `require(output > amount, "Need to recoup the loan amount"`

Code can be seen here: https://gist.github.com/frankandrobot/296187ca4ef8c56462fb7e897e7d3b05

The contract is called by a hardhat script that gives this error:

```
{
  reason: 'cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit',
  code: 'UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT',
  error: ProviderError: execution reverted: Need to recoup the loan amount
      at HttpProvider.request (/Users/uriel/Documents/mazinger/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:78:19)
      at HDWalletProvider.request (/Users/uriel/Documents/mazinger/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/accounts.ts:188:34)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at async EthersProviderWrapper.send (/Users/uriel/Documents/mazinger/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20),
  method: 'estimateGas',
  transaction: {
    from: '0x55c60220584D51822B384ceF632e88940D2A46C6',
    to: '0xb6Ab2fbBc625d845728509302A4E4649131b456a',
    data: '0xde76fef500000000000000000000000021be370d5312f44cb42ce377bc9b8a0cef1a4c8300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001b48eb57e000000000000000000000000000f491e7b69e4244ad4002bc14e878a34207e38c290000000000000000000000006d0176c5ea1e44b08d3dd001b0784ce42f47a3a700000000000000000000000004068da6c83afcfa0e13ba15a6696662335d5b75',
    accessList: null
  }
}
```